C++ vector: for loop to std::transform
I got a code in the following form
vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3 };
vector<int> vec2{ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

for (int i = 0; i < vec2.size(); i++) {
    if (vec2[i] % 2 == 0)
        vec.push_back(vec2[i]);
}

How can I use std::transform to get rid of the for loop? Thanks for help :)
I tried something like:
std::transform(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), ...);

but I'm not sure what to add in the last place (where the ... are).

Also, why do you have a problem with loops? I would just replace the for with a nicer one: for (int value: vec2) { if (value%2==0) vec.push_back(value); }

In all seriousness, I like your code just the way it is.  I can see exactly what is going on.

@Jason With std::copy_if you also know exactly what is going on plus the benefit of conciseness (increased readability).

That's your opinion, and that's fine.  I disagree on readability, but that's subjective.

To me, if a range-based for is used in this code, it'll be much more readable than std::copy_if with a back inserter and a lambda. At least, that lambda should be given a name.

transform is for converting types of elements not for filtering.

You cannot be more explicit than "copy if" since OP basically wants to copy vec2 to vec1 if  (good names combined with conciseness makes readability)

@Fareanor I see your argument and don't disagree entirely.  We just disagree on how we define readability.  If we assume a company full of RocketSearchers (not a bad thing), everyone at the company will able to read the original code and understand exactly what is happening without question.  He didn't know about std::copy_if or its arguments, or its caveats, or its performance implications.  So, if he comes across it in code, he'd be doing himself a disservice by not stopping and looking up documentation.  So, in my opinion, the original is more readable.

I wouldn't use std::transform() for this.   The loop is fine, but fanatic loop-removers can use std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2),[](int x) {return x % 2 == 0; });.

You fundamentally misunderstand what std::transform is. It’s not a replacement for all for loops. Rather, for is a low-level language construct that can be used to express various algorithms across ranges. std::transform is one of these algorithms. But the loop you have is expressing a different algorithm (which is generally known as a filter, but in C++ it has a different name — just as C++ std::transform is usually known by different names, such as map).

Dupes: Fast way to push_back a vector many times and Alternative for std:vector to remove its elements while going through a loop?

What you want is a std::copy_if:
    std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> vec2{ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::copy_if(vec2.cbegin(),vec2.cend(),std::back_inserter(vec),[](const int num){
        return num % 2 == 0;
    });
    for(auto&& i : vec) {
        std::cout << i;
    }

std::copy_if copies element from one range to another, using a predicate as the selection criteria.
std::transform is a mapping from one range to another: T -> transform-> U

The output loop can be replaced with  std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));   (if outputting vec, otherwise output vec2 instead).

It could be better to move lambda into a named variable isEven to make it clear what's doing without analysis of its body.

@Peter ostream_iterator is extremely noisy for just printing such a simple vector

@Raildex   The copy_if() call is similarly noisy (particularly since the OP's loop can easily be written in a form similar to your output loop, to highlight that noisiness).  My point is, if the goal is to avoid (explicitly) writing loops, there are options.

std::transform is wrong tool for the job. It cannot filter elements based on condition, all elements from input range must be placed (after transformation) in the output range.
Use std::copy_if instead:
std::copy_if(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](int i){return i % 2 == 0;});

